# The number of solutions of the equation $p^x=x^q$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p, q$ be two real non negative numbers.
How many solutions has the equation $p^x=x^q$ (considering all possible cases of $p,q$)?

Comment: and what is x? an integer?

Comment: no, a real number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $a^b$ is defined for $a\ne 0$ and $b\in\mathbb Z$ per repeated multiplication and possibly teking reciprocals; for $a>0$ and $b\in\mathbb R$ by $a^b:=\exp(b\ln(a))$; for $a=0$ as $0^b=0$ for $b>0$; for $a=b=0$ as $0^0=1$; for all other cases $a^b$ is not defined (over the reals). And even $0^0=1$ may make many frown.

For simplicity, let us assume $a^b$ is only defined when $a>0$. The remainig cases (i.e. where $p\le 0$ or we want to include solutions $x\le 0$) are left as an exercise.

So we assume $p>0$ and look for $x>0$ with $$\exp(x\ln p)=\exp(q\ln x)$$
or equivalently
$$ \frac{x}{\ln x}=\frac q{\ln p}.$$
You should make a sketch of the graph of $x\mapsto \frac{x}{\ln x}$ for $x\in(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ to see how solvability and number of solutions depend on the RHS $\frac q{\ln p}$.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions in terms of the [Lambert W-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertw) is
$$x = - \frac{q W(\frac{-\ln(p)}{q})}{\ln p}$$

Comment: Just as a reminder: the case $p=1$ is missing.

Comment: and how many values does the lambert function have in these cases

Comment: It is not so simple. For example, in the case $p=\sqrt{2}$ and $q= \frac {17} {5}$ that formula produces a lot of complex roots.

Comment: Depends on the value of $\frac{-\ln(p)}{q}$, there will be at most two real solutions.